# Rotating a 2D Image Towards a Point in C#

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, textures

I have been working with rotating Texture2D sprites. I have been using:

> float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
>   RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;

and

> ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(car, screenpos, null, Color.White, RotationAngle, car_origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

for the most part to handle the rotation of my test texture "car". It seems like the rotation angle of Pi*2 is a value between 0 and -6.283185 or 0 and 6.283185 depending on the direction. Now what I would like to do is rotate a texture in a certain direction (say the texture is an arrow) towards a location (a vector2 such as the current mouse position). I am not quite sure how to go about how I'd need to modify this rotation angle based on a vector2 position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to wrap an angle when passing it to `SpriteBatch.Draw`. But if you do want to wrap an angle for some reason, it's best to use `MathHelper.WrapAngle` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.wrapangle.aspx)).

Now say you have a `Vector2` that represents a direction and a distance (as you might have, for example, if you did `mousePos - carPos`, for the direction and distance from the car to the cursor). And you want to take that direction and convert it to an angle. Use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) like this one:

```
public static float Angle(this Vector2 v)
{
    return (float)Math.Atan2(v.Y, v.X);
}
```

So, to get your angle you'd do something like: `(mousePos - carPos).Angle()`.

See the [documentation for `Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx) for more details.

Comment: You sir are a genius. I just tried that out and it works great, thank you!